# What is A TokenList class in GCM Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've looked on the Google's GCM Documentation for Android I've Done Every thing but the problem is that in "MyInstanceIDService" . what is TokenList

```
public class MyInstanceIDService extends InstanceIDListenerService {
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    refreshAllTokens();
}

private void refreshAllTokens() {
    // assuming you have defined TokenList as
    // some generalized store for your tokens
    ArrayList<TokenList> tokenList = TokensList.get();
    InstanceID iid = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
    for(tokenItem : tokenList) {
        tokenItem.token =
                iid.getToken(tokenItem.authorizedEntity,tokenItem.scope,tokenItem.options);
        // send this tokenItem.token to your server
    }
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

> `TokensList` is an array of `TokenList`

It's just a store for your tokens where
you can manage (update / delete) tokens on the server side.

Here is the example for `MyInstanceIDService.class` to refresh all tokens and do your task for tokens at the server end:

```
public class MyInstanceIDService extends InstanceIDListenerService {
        public void onTokenRefresh() {
            refreshAllTokens();
        }

        private void refreshAllTokens() {
            // assuming you have defined TokenList as
            // some generalized store for your tokens
            ArrayList<TokenList> tokenList = TokensList.get();
            InstanceID iid = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            for (tokenItem : tokenList) {
                tokenItem.token = iid.getToken(tokenItem.authorizedEntity, tokenItem.scope, tokenItem.options);
                // send this tokenItem.token to your server
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: from where is TokenList Class ?